# XMLHttpRequest degrades performance?

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have a situation in which i make a call to a `xml` file that contains information of teams. since we have large number of teams so it takes some time to load the data.

So i came up to a solution to create different `xml` for each team.now i'll have to make different call for each file or i'll use lazy loading , so which approach is better loading full file once or dividing it into several parts.

I Need some suggestion regarding `javascript http` request i have gone through the following documents [how it degrades performance](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1851233) [link2](https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/PUB/Best+Practices+on+JavaScript+and+AJAX+Performance). and came to know that more number of `xmlHttpRequest` degrades your performance.

Size of full file - `1.79 mb` size on disk -  `1.80 mb`

Size after splitting - `1.78 mb` size on disk - `2.84 mb`

Comment: How many files. What's their sizes. What's the size of the single file.

Comment: updated plz have a look @JaromandaX

Comment: How many files when split. Seems odd the spilt size is less

Comment: Personally I'd stick with a single request. I thought the size would be much larger. Just make sure you load it asynchronously

Comment: 429 files after splitting

Comment: ya file is loading aysnc

Comment: Single download for sure

Answer (score -1):

It is true that more the number of requests the slower the performance, as browsers has specific limits to make requests simultaneously.

You could just convert the xml into a text file and try to request the file as it will reduce the load of the file to some extent.

You could then parse the text file as a JSON and consume it as per your requirement.

Try to break the file into 2 or 3 segments and then make call.

Comment: its not about breaking in 2 ,3 parts will divide it into number of teams

Comment: Then the requests will increase drastically and your performance will degrade